# To improve the Superuser search feature by allowing partially match ("like", "contains") logic

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, search

I asked this question:

[Type to navigate and open anything on screen by using keyboard ? Similar to shortcatapp.com](https://superuser.com/questions/717486/type-to-navigate-and-open-anything-on-screen-by-using-keyboard-similar-to-shor)

In the content, there is the term "shortcatapp". But when I search using that term, results = 0. When I search "http://shortcatapp.com", then there is a result.

It looks like the search is using "exact match" rather than "contains" or "like".

It'll be very useful if SU allow partially match search. Sometime user won't remember the full phrases and it's where partially match search shine.

Answer (score 6):

Searching "partial matches" is already possible. If you search for `*shortcatapp*`, you'll get [the expected result](https://superuser.com/search?q=*shortcatapp*).

Enabling partial matches by default would only lead to bad precision in the search results, meaning you'd get a lot of irrelevant posts.